# Freemarker / Spring MVC / Dojo integration

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, integration, freemarker

has anyone been successful in using dojo > 1.6 to declaratively build widgets with the spring MVC toolkit inside of Freemarker templates ?

More precisely, Freemarker chokes when transitioning from old style dojo (which we used until now) as in :

```
<@form.select path="fruit" dojoType="dojo.dijit.Select"/>
```

to the new dojo syntax (which we would like to use), as in :

```
<@form.select path="fruit" data-dojo-type="dojo/dijit/Select"/>
```

It is worth mentioning that the transition works with plain HTML elemnts, as in :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojo/layout/TabContainer"/>
```

Hence, it seems the use of "dashed attribute names" is not possible for external taglibs included in FTL pages.

Can anyone confirm this, or, by any chance, show how it can be done ?

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "freemarker chokes"? It produces errors? If no template errors occur, take a look at source generate by freemarker and show us what freemarker produces vs what you would like it to produce. Also what is the source of the form.select macro (e.g. how does import look like)?

Comment: Just for completeness sake, the error message generated by Freemarker : `Error parsing included template WEB-INF/ftl/welcome/./form/searchform.ftl Encountered "-" at line 131, column 67 in WEB-INF/ftl/welcome/form/searchform.ftl. Was expecting: "=" `. And, the form.select is not an FTL macro but a tag supplied by the Spring-MVC Form tag library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yip, the FreeMarker 2.3 syntax can't handle dashes in parameter names as those are subtractions and then a comparison in it. That can't even be changed without breaking backward   compatibility. As things stand, FreeMarker 2.4 target that and some other problems that require syntactical changes, but that's far away.

What most do is using `date_foo` instead of `data-foo` and then replace the `_` with `-` when they print the attribute name. However, `@form.select` wasn't written by you, so it can get tricky. Well if you are lucky, it's a `TemplateDirectiveModel` and then you can write your own `TemplateDirectiveModel` that delegates to it after doing the replacements... but if it's a macro, you are out of luck.

I wonder if 2.3.21 should just allow `foo\-bar\-baaz` or something like that as an identifier... ugly but at least a solution before 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. While waiting for 2.4, we'll try a workaround based on a JavaScript onLoad() function handling the dojo dashed attributes. If it works, I'll share the code in the anwser to this question.